# The pitch of はららか

Tags: pitch-accent

I'm wondering what the pitch of the はららか in is:

> **はららか**に流す涙のように頬を撫でていった

If I'm not dumb, the definition is:

> 静かに、はらはらと鳴る音を表わす (https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AF%E3%82%89%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B-2075765)

However, I couldn't find anything else about it like pitch. However, it popped up in a song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxD9zU9jevo&ab_channel=%E3%82%81%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B. If you follow the link, the line is at 01:55.

I know that the pitch can change of words especially in pop songs.

My question is if the pitch for "はららか" in the song is also the same for daily speech (I couldn't find it in the dictionary, nor anyone pronouncing it on Forvo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

はららか would be pronounced はららか{LHLL} (similar to うららか{LHLL}、きららか{LHLL} etc).

It’s a bit hard to say if the song matches it but it seems like it mostly does to me.

But pitch in songs generally ignores pitch accent over half of the time (except in rap which tends to be a little closer to speech) so it’s a bit fruitless to try and learn pitch accent from songs.